# Javascript <tbody> swapping not working

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a couple tables whose content should change based on clicking certain buttons (in this case, links).  I've used this Javascript code elsewhere successfully, though with only one parameter in the switchid() function (there was only one table to mess around with).  I keep researching examples of this and I seem to be passing the variables correctly, so what am I doing wrong?  This code doesn't work on Chrome or IE:

**Edit: Per the comments, I was able to whittle my javascript section down to a single, smaller function, that should do the same thing.  I have made the change below.  It still doesn't work, though.**

I also changed my "array" and "x" variables to "JonArray" and "JonX" to avoid any chances of one of those being a reserved word.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var topTable = new Array('English','Spanish');
            var bottomTable = new Array('Japanese','Italian');

            function switchid(JonArray,JonX) {
                for(var i=0;i<JonArray.length();i++) {
                    document.getElementById(JonX).style.display='none';
                }
                document.getElementById(JonX).style.display='table-row-group';
            }

        </script>
        <table border='1'>
            <thead>
                <tr><td>Odds</td><td>Evens</td></tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr><td><a href="javascript:switchid('topTable','English')">English</a></td><td><a href="javascript:switchid('topTable','Spanish')">Spanish</a></td></tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody id='English'>
                <tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Three</td><td>Four</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody id='Spanish' style="display:none;">
                <tr><td>Uno</td><td>Dos</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Tres</td><td>Quatro</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br />
        <table border='1'>
            <thead>
                <tr><td>Odds</td><td>Evens</td></tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr><td><a href="javascript:switchid('bottomTable','Japanese')">Japanese</a></td><td><a href="javascript:switchid('bottomTable','Italian')">Italian</a></td></tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody id='Japanese'>
                <tr><td>Ichi</td><td>Ni</td></tr>
                <tr><td>San</td><td>Shi</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody id='Italian' style="display:none;">
                <tr><td>Un</td><td>Due</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Tre</td><td>Quattro</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: (I should've titled this post "tFready Friday" (tBody swapping... get it?)

Comment: "Swap" `int i=0;` to `var i=0;` in a `for` loop in `hideall()`. Also `document.all` is IE only stuff, though it doesn't work like jQuery...

Comment: FWIW, `document.getElementById` has been standard forever. You can get rid of all the `document.all` and `document.layers` stuff

Comment: There is no need to keep `document.layers` and `document.all` branches in the code in 2013. AFAIK, there is no browser that understands `display:table-row-group`, but doesn't understand `document.getElementById`. Moreover, these branches are written incorrectly (instead of `.id` there should be `[x]`).

Comment: Thanks Ilya and Jeffman... Teemu, I'm not sure what you're saying about my loop...?

Comment: Just realized I left the "alert" in the switchid() function, was using that as a test.  It never alerts me, so I'm assuming that function never successfully gets called.

Comment: I get what you mean about the loop now.  I have changed it to "var" instead of "int" but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/92ZPM/1/

I made sure the function and variables were available regardless of when they are created.

I also gave your variables descriptive names, cleaned up and stored the table data in a single object.

**JavaScript**

```
window.switchid = function (table, language) {
    var tables = {
        'top': ['English', 'Spanish'],
        'bottom': ['Japanese', 'Italian']
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < tables[table].length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(tables[table][i]).style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById(language).style.display =
        'table-row-group';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table border='1'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Odds</td>
            <td>Evens</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="javascript:switchid('top','English');">English</a>
            </td>
            <td><a href="javascript:switchid('top','Spanish')">Spanish</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody id='English'>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id='Spanish' style="display:none;">
        <tr>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<table border='1'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Odds</td>
            <td>Evens</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="javascript:switchid('bottom','Japanese')">Japanese</a>
            </td>
            <td><a href="javascript:switchid('bottom','Italian')">Italian</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody id='Japanese'>
        <tr>
            <td>Ichi</td>
            <td>Ni</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>San</td>
            <td>Shi</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id='Italian' style="display:none;">
        <tr>
            <td>Un</td>
            <td>Due</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tre</td>
            <td>Quattro</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This worked!  And I didn't have to change any of my existing HTML by changing the 'top' and 'bottom' names in JS to 'topTable' and 'bottomTable'

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your javascript a little:

```
        var tables=new Array();
        tables['topTable'] = new Array('English','Spanish');
        tables['bottomTable'] = new Array('Japanese','Italian');

        function switchid(JonArray,JonX) {
            //alert(JonArray);
            var tmptable=tables[JonArray];
            for(var i=0;i < tmptable.length;i++) {
                document.getElementById(tmptable[i]).style.display='none';
            }
            document.getElementById(JonX).style.display='';
        }
```

Comment: This looks good, but it's not working for me.  The logic looks sound, I'm just not sure why it's not working.  I do get alerted now when I click one of the languages, so that function does run.

Comment: change the line in your for loop to document.getElementById(tmptable[i]).style.display='none';    that will hide both the tbody's, then your last line will be document.getElementById(JonX).style.display='';

Comment: I edited the switch id function with the comment notes, hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Some of these answers work, but I just caught the **REAL** answer via Chrome DevTools!  In my 'for' loop I was using 'length()' instead of 'length'!!!

Answer (score -2):

Why not to use CSS instead of looping through IDs?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W9tE9/)

HTML

```
<table border='1' class="English">
    <thead>
        <tr><td>Odds</td><td>Evens</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><td onclick="changeLang(this,'English')">English</td><td onclick="changeLang(this,'Spanish')">Spanish</td></tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody id='English'>
        <tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Three</td><td>Four</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id='Spanish'>
        <tr><td>Uno</td><td>Dos</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Tres</td><td>Quatro</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
tbody {
    display: none;
}

.English #English, .Spanish #Spanish, .Japanese #Japanese, .Italian #Italian {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

JS

```
function changeLang(cell, lang) {
    cell.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className = lang;
}
```

Comment: Because nobody asked for CSS.

Comment: But you already use CSS `display` property. Why just not to use it in a more convenient way?

Comment: It didn't even work for me; Nothing was displayed in the tables.

Comment: The fiddle works, but the page hosted on IIS on my local machine seen through Chrome and IE doesn't work.  I'm probably doing something wrong then.

Comment: I changed HTML a bit relatively to your initial code, removed `style` from the `tbody` but added `class` to the `table`.